# Can we use OAuth 2 (access token) instead of Subscription Key in APIM and does it have any effect?

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to using access token to manage user who want to access my api on APIm and remove subscription key. Can we do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

On the settings tab there is a setting to disable the API key called subscription required:

[image]

Adding JWT token validation can be added through a policy. There are examples in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are header-based authentication but in Oauth the platform will provide the access token instead of you going to portal and getting the subscription key.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2) for more indepth explanation.